# How to Load Child Object in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-one

How can I load the child object (RefAuthorizationVO) when I load the Parent Object (DuaVO) object.

**Main Class Method to load**

```
DuaVO dua = (DuaVO) session.get(DuaVO.class, "1");
```

**RefAuthorization** Child

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RFRNC_AUTHRZTN")
public class RefAuthorizationVO implements Serializable
{
    @Column(name = "SYS_CREAT_USER_ID")
    private String sysCreatedUserId;

    @Column(name = "SYS_CREAT_TS")
    private Date sysCreatedTimestamp;

    @Column(name = "SYS_UPDT_USER_ID")
    private String sysUpdateUserId;

    @Column(name = "SYS_UPDT_TS")
    private Date sysUpdateTimestamp;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="AUTHRZTN_CD")
    private String authorizationCode;

    @Column(name="AUTHRZTN_DESC")
    private String authorizationDescription;
```

**DuaVO** Parent

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DUA")
public class DuaVO implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name= "DUA_NUM")
    private String duaNumber;

    // AuditDetails

    @Column(name = "SYS_CREAT_USER_ID")
    private String sysCreatedUserId;

    @Column(name = "SYS_CREAT_TS")
    private Date sysCreatedTimestamp;

    @Column(name = "SYS_UPDT_USER_ID")
    private String sysUpdateUserId;

    @Column(name = "SYS_UPDT_TS")
    private Date sysUpdateTimestamp;

    @Column(name = "DUA_SHRT_DESC")
    private String duaShortDesc;

    @Column(name = "AUTHRZTN_CD")
    private String authorizationCode;

    @ManyToOne
    private RefAuthorizationVO refAuthorizationVO; 

    }
```

But, when I try to access the child like this..

```
System.out.println("Ref Auth: " + dua.getRefAuthorizationVO() );
```

I get null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you missed @JoinColumn annotation

```
@JoinColumn(name = "FK_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
@ManyToOne
```